# In a batch file, how can I get the value of an environment variable whose name is the value of another environment variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file

If I know that one environment variable contains the name of another, how can I get the value of the second environment variable?

Assume I have a file `java.properties` alongside my batch file with the following contents.

```
JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR=JAVA_HOME_1_7_0_17
```

What I want to do is check if `JAVA_HOME_1_7_0_17` is set and, if so, do the equivalent of `set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME_1_7_0_17%`.  I can figure out what environment variable I'm looking for, but I don't know how to get its value.  This is what I have so far...

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if exist %~dp0\java.properties (
    echo "Found java properties."

    for /F "tokens=1* usebackq delims==" %%A IN (%~dp0\java.properties) DO (
        if "%%A"=="JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR" set JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR=%%B
    )

    if not [!JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR!] == [] (
        echo "Override var is !JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR!"
        REM This is where I'm stuck!!!
        REM Assume JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR is JAVA_HOME_1_7_0_17
    )
)

endlocal & set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%
```

What I want to do is check if the environment variable `JAVA_HOME_1_7_0_17` exists and, if it does, use its value to set `JAVA_HOME`.

### Updated

I think the nested if statements are making things more difficult then needed.  I got rid of them and the following seems to work.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if not exist "%~dp0\java.properties" (
    goto:EOF
)

for /F "tokens=1* usebackq delims==" %%A IN ("%~dp0\java.properties") DO (
    if "%%A"=="JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR" set JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR=%%B
)

if [!JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR!] == [] (
    goto:EOF
)

set JAVA_HOME=!%JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR%!

endlocal & set JAVA_HOME="%JAVA_HOME%"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `set JAVA_HOME=%!JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR!%`.

**EDIT:** This should not work if `!JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR!` was set on the same line. Try

```
call set JAVA_HOME=!%JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR%!
```

a downside being that since it will search the disk for a file/executable with the name `set`, the command should take slightly longer to finish, though it should only be noticeable in large loops.

**EDIT 2:** Try this too...

(add `set override=0` in front, add `set override=1` under `if not`, and replace the `endlocal` line)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set override=0

if exist %~dp0\java.properties (
    echo "Found java properties."

    for /F "tokens=1* usebackq delims==" %%A IN (%~dp0\java.properties) DO (
        if "%%A"=="JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR" set JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR=%%B
    )

    if not [!JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR!] == [] (
        echo "Override var is !JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR!"
        set override=1
        REM Assume JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR is JAVA_HOME_1_7_0_17
    )
)

endlocal & if override=1 set JAVA_HOME=!%JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR%!
```

Comment: That works if I get rid of the nested if statements.  I don't know what the difference is, but the basic syntax is all I need to make it work good enough.  Thanks.

Comment: No it doesn't.  The variable always ended up blank.

Comment: So the variable is still blank when you put `call set JAVA_HOME=!%JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR%!` at the portion where you were stuck?

Comment: I also added another version which just sets a variable if an override is needed and then does it after everything is done.

Comment: Yeah, it was still blank.  The syntax you gave me works fine if I leave out the if statements which is good enough for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I would use FINDSTR to filter out the relevant line, IF DEFINED to validate the existence of the variable, and delayed expansion within the loop to get the appropriate value.

Your code could be as simple as:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in (
  '2^>nul findstr /bil "JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE_ENV_VAR=" "%~dp0\java.properties"'
) do if defined %%B set "JAVA_HOME=!%%B!"
endlocal & set "JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%"
```